# Native functions throw UnsatisfiedLinkError in custom view, despite working in main activity

Tags: java, c++, android, android-ndk, android-ndk-r5

For some reason I can only call native functions from my main activity and not any custom views that I've created. Here is an example file (I followed a tutorial, but renamed the classes http://mindtherobot.com/blog/452/android-beginners-ndk-setup-step-by-step/)

See the usage of the native function "getNewString".

```
package com.example.native;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

public class NativeTestActivity extends Activity
{   
    static
    {
        System.loadLibrary("nativeTest");
    }

    private native String getNewString();

    @Override public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);        
        this.setContentView(new BitmapView(this));

        String hello = getNewString(); // This line works fine
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setMessage(hello).show();
    }
}

class BitmapView extends View
{
    static
    {
        System.loadLibrary("nativeTest");
    }

    private native String getNewString();

    public BitmapView(Context context)
    {
        super(context);

        String hello = getNewString(); // This line throws the UnsatisfiedLinkError
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this.getContext()).setMessage(hello).show();
    }
}
```

How can I call native functions in my custom views?

I've built the application as an Android 2.2 app. I'm running the application on my HTC Desire. I have the latest SDK (9) and latest NDK (r5).

Comment: do you have libnativeTest.so file? does your respective c file function have similar signature? I am curious about that

Comment: Yes it does, as you can see from the comments above, when calling the native function in the activity it works absolutely fine, but attempting to use it in a view fails. The .so file can be made from the tutorial link above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you are trying to call the native function from a class where it dont belongs to.

You defined the following JNI function in your c file:

`jstring Java_com_example_native_NativeTestActivity_getNewString()`

This states that the native function when loaded will bind with the method declared as native in **NativeTestActivity** class. So when you try to call it from your **View** class it doesn't find any function to bind to.

In that case it will look for the following function (which of course does not exist in your .so):

`jstring Java_com_example_native_BitmapView_getNewString()`

If you still want to be able to call the same function from different classes you can declare it in a container class that can be accessed from any class you want.

eg:

**java code**:

```
package com.example.native;
public class NativeHelper {
     public native String getNewString();
     static
     {
         System.loadLibrary("nativeTest");
     }
}
```

**c code:**

```
jstring Java_com_example_native_NativeHelper_getNewString(JNIEnv* env, jobject javaThis)
{
     return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, "Hello from native code!");
}
```

Comment: Great idea with the native helper class. Can't believe I forgot about the renaming of the C function. Thanks.